# Map names for properties in Get-WinEvent

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise, get-winevent

When I do this request

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName='Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-Gateway/Operational'; Id=307,302,303; StartTime='01.11.2022 0:00:01'} | Select-Object TimeCreated, ID, Message, Properties | Format-Table -AutoSize | Export-Clixml xml.xml
```

I get response with non-named properties, such as

```
<Obj RefId="19">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty</ToString>
                <Props>
                  <S N="Value">6280</S>
                </Props>
              </Obj>
```

How can I name properties according to how they are called in System log? As in Example on image
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiJ7h.png)

Comment: Take out format-table if you're going to export it.

Comment: Events have a `.ToXml()` method btw, that might give you a much better output than `Export-CliXml`

Comment: For example `get-winevent system | select -first 5 | % { ([xml]$_.toxml()).event.eventdata.data }`